# kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

I´m trying to use django with celery and rabbitmq on containers Docker. It works well without docker, but when I run on containers I recieve this erro : kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused.

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.12.0-management
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    restart: always
  celery:
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A loan  worker --loglevel=info
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    restart: always
  loan:
    image: loan
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - celery
```

I saw some people saying to put

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

on **init**.py, but I already put on it.

Comment: What's trying to connect to what, with what hostname or URL?  Just the Compose configuration you show doesn't seem to be enough to reproduce the issue.